# Search for a specific text which is stored in a cloumn from a cell which has so much data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have a column full of address from a state. In another column I have all districts of the state. I want to extract district out of the address. I tried different formulas, but didnt work.

For eg:

**Address Column**

S.V.N. Road, Warangal, Andhra Pradesh

Vuyyur, Distt., Krishna, Andhra Pradesh

Nagarjunasagar, Vijayapuri South,, Distt., Guntur

Paritala (PO), Kanchikacherla, (MD), Krishna (DT)

Tekkali, Srikakulam Distt.,, Andhra Pradesh
etc

**Districts column**

Warangal

Krishna

Guntur

Srikakulam
etc

I want a formula or VBA code that searches Districts from districts column inside the address column and extract district. Please note Districts are not in a specific place in address Cell.

Comment: Edit your request to show specifically what you tried, and what you got for results; as well as specifically what your desired results would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$5,MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$2:D$5,A2)),0,1),0),1),"District not in list")
```

Entered as array formula by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.
Enter this adjacent to your first address.(below it is in `B2` and address is on `A2`)
Change it to suit your need.
I assumed that your data looks like this.

[image: sample image]

As you can see, I put the District List on `D2:D5` so in the formula, change it to where your list is.
If the no match is found, it will return `District not in list` as seen in `B6`.
I believe every address have a unique Disrtict?
If ever the adress contains two(2) Districts, it will return the first found District in the address.

**How does the formula work?**

```
=SEARCH(D$2:D$5,A2)
```

This searches each word found in `D2:D5` (your districts) in address in `A2`.
The result is an array of error values and numbers.
Considering `A2` it returns `{#Value!, #Value!, 14, #Value!}`.

To handle the errors we add `ISERROR` combined with `IF`.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$2:D$5,A2),0,1)
```

This replaces `#VALUE!` with `0` and non-error value with `1`.
Now it returns `{0, 0, 1, 0}`.

Now, you want to return the District of the corresponding address.
To do that we will use `INDEX` and `MATCH` combination.
First we use `MATCH` to know the row number of our District.
We already have this array `{0, 0, 1, 0}`, we need to match `1`.

```
=MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$2:D$5,A2),0,1),0)
```

Simplified:

```
=MATCH(1,{0, 0, 1, 0}, 0)
```

And yields `3`.

Finally, we use `INDEX` to return the `District` of the corresponding address.

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$5,MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$2:D$5,A2)),0,1),0),1)
```

Simplified:

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$5,3,1)
```

The last argument which is `[column]` can be omitted since you only have 1.
Or you can specify it as `1`.

This yields to `Warangal`.
Note that we added `IFERROR` to handle non-existing District.
Hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a custom function that

- Reads in the Address cell
- Loops through comma delimited address section by section to get a
  substring
- Does a lookup of the substring from a range containing a list of all possible districts
- If found it will return the district to your District column, otherwise it will continue looping until you get to the end of the address contents

Input: S.V.N. Road, Warangal, Andhra Pradesh 
  Lookup "S.V.N. Road" in districts
    Not found, continue
  Lookup "Warangal" in districts
    Found, enter in Districts column, end function

If possible, it would be helpful to have the address formatted regularly so the District would always appear after the Nth comma so you could simply select the Nth+1 substring for District.

Answer (score 0):

```
Take the value of A Column and B column.

Dim storACellVal As Variant
Sub Test()
lngLastCell = Application.CountA(Columns(1))
for i= 1 to lngLastCell
Acellno = "A" & i
Bcellno = "B" & i
'It will store the datas of column A into aColVal
aColVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Acellno).Value
'It will store the datas of column B into bColVal
bColVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Bcellno).Value

storACellVal=split(aColVal,",")
for j=0 to UBound(storACellVal)
    if trim(storACellVal(j)=trim(bColVal) then
        msgbox "True"
    End if
next j
Next i
End Sub

I hope this might help you. I apologies, if I did anything wrong.
```

Comment: This is the Excel function **=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B1,A1,1))=FALSE,TRUE)**. Copy and paste it into cell other than A and B. I hope, I am giving you right suggestion.